# how to use AVAssetWriter to write h264 strem into video?

Tags: avfoundation, h.264, avassetwriter

I want to make the h.264 stream from server to a video file, but when I used `assetwrite.finishwrite`, the XCode reports

```
Video /var/mobile/Applications/DE4196F1-BB77-4B7D-8C20-7A5D6223C64D/Documents/test.mov cannot be saved to the saved photos album: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12847 "This movie format is not supported." UserInfo=0x5334830 {NSLocalizedDescription=This movie format is not supported.}"
```

Below is my code:
data is the h.264 frame, just one frame, it might be i frame or p.

```
(void)_encodeVideoFrame2:(NSData *) data time:(double)tm 
{
  CMBlockBufferRef videoBlockBuffer=NULL;
  CMFormatDescriptionRef videoFormat=NULL;
  CMSampleBufferRef videoSampleBuffer=NULL;
  CMItemCount numberOfSampleTimeEntries=1;
  CMItemCount numberOfSamples=1;
  CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCMVideoCodecType_H264, 320, 240, NULL, &videoFormat);
  OSStatus result;
  result=CMBlockBufferCreateWithMemoryBlock(kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL, data.length, kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL, 0, data.length, kCMBlockBufferAssureMemoryNowFlag, &videoBlockBuffer);
  result=CMBlockBufferReplaceDataBytes(data.bytes, videoBlockBuffer, 0, data.length);
  CMSampleTimingInfo videoSampleTimingInformation={CMTimeMake(tm*600, 600)};
  size_t sampleSizeArray[1];
  sampleSizeArray[0]=data.length;
  result=CMSampleBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, videoBlockBuffer, TRUE, NULL, NULL, videoFormat, numberOfSamples, numberOfSampleTimeEntries, &videoSampleTimingInformation, 1, sampleSizeArray, &videoSampleBuffer);
  result = CMSampleBufferMakeDataReady(videoSampleBuffer);
  [assetWriterInput appendSampleBuffer:videoSampleBuffer]; 
}
```

maybe the `CMSampleBufferCreate` arguments are wrong？ Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In order to mux already compressed h264 buffers with `AVAssetWriter`, you have to specify a `nil` OutputSettings, contrary to what the documentation states.

So, instead of doing

```
videoInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput alloc] 
    initWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:@{
        AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecH264,
    }
    sourceFormatHint:myVideoFormat
];
```

you should be doing

```
videoInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput alloc] 
    initWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
    outputSettings:nil
    sourceFormatHint:myVideoFormat
];
```

This will let you do pass-through of video or audio data, without AVAssetWriterInput trying to encode/transcode anything for you.

Answer (score -2):

## Try this code

- (IBAction)createVideo:(id)sender {

  ///////////// setup OR function def if we move this to a separate function ////////////
  // this should be moved to its own function, that can take an imageArray, videoOutputPath, etc...
  //    - (void)exportImages:(NSMutableArray *)imageArray
  // asVideoToPath:(NSString *)videoOutputPath
  // withFrameSize:(CGSize)imageSize
  // framesPerSecond:(NSUInteger)fps {

  NSError *error = nil;

  // set up file manager, and file videoOutputPath, remove "test_output.mp4" if it exists...
  //NSString *videoOutputPath = @"/Users/someuser/Desktop/test_output.mp4";
  NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
  NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory()
                                  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
  NSString *videoOutputPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test_output.mp4"];
  //NSLog(@"-->videoOutputPath= %@", videoOutputPath);
  // get rid of existing mp4 if exists...
  if ([fileMgr removeItemAtPath:videoOutputPath error:&error] != YES)
      NSLog(@"Unable to delete file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

  CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(400, 200);
  NSUInteger fps = 30;

  //NSMutableArray *imageArray;
  //imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"download.jpeg", @"download2.jpeg", nil];
  NSMutableArray *imageArray;
  NSArray* imagePaths = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"jpg" inDirectory:nil];
  imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:imagePaths.count];
  NSLog(@"-->imageArray.count= %i", imageArray.count);
  for (NSString* path in imagePaths)
  {
      [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]];
      //NSLog(@"-->image path= %@", path);
  }

  //////////////     end setup    ///////////////////////////////////

  NSLog(@"Start building video from defined frames.");

  AVAssetWriter *videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:
                                [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoOutputPath] fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
                                                            error:&error];
  NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);

  NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:imageSize.width], AVVideoWidthKey,
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:imageSize.height], AVVideoHeightKey,
                                 nil];

  AVAssetWriterInput* videoWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput
                                          assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                          outputSettings:videoSettings];

  AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor
                                                   assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:videoWriterInput
                                                   sourcePixelBufferAttributes:nil];

  NSParameterAssert(videoWriterInput);
  NSParameterAssert([videoWriter canAddInput:videoWriterInput]);
  videoWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
  [videoWriter addInput:videoWriterInput];

  //Start a session:
  [videoWriter startWriting];
  [videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];

  CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL;

  //convert uiimage to CGImage.
  int frameCount = 0;
  double numberOfSecondsPerFrame = 6;
  double frameDuration = fps * numberOfSecondsPerFrame;

  //for(VideoFrame * frm in imageArray)
  NSLog(@"**************************************************");
  for(UIImage * img in imageArray)
  {
      //UIImage * img = frm._imageFrame;
      buffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage:[img CGImage]];

  ```
  BOOL append_ok = NO;
  int j = 0;
  while (!append_ok && j < 30) {
      if (adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData)  {
          //print out status:
          NSLog(@"Processing video frame (%d,%d)",frameCount,[imageArray count]);

          CMTime frameTime = CMTimeMake(frameCount*frameDuration,(int32_t) fps);
          append_ok = [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:frameTime];
          if(!append_ok){
              NSError *error = videoWriter.error;
              if(error!=nil) {
                  NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@,%@.", error, [error userInfo]);
              }
          }
      }
      else {
          printf("adaptor not ready %d, %d\n", frameCount, j);
          [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
      }
      j++;
  }
  if (!append_ok) {
      printf("error appending image %d times %d\n, with error.", frameCount, j);
  }
  frameCount++;
  ```

  }
  NSLog(@"**************************************************");

  //Finish the session:
  [videoWriterInput markAsFinished];
  [videoWriter finishWriting];
  NSLog(@"Write Ended");

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //////////////  OK now add an audio file to move file  /////////////////////
  AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

  NSString *bundleDirectory = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
  // audio input file...
  NSString *audio_inputFilePath = [bundleDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"30secs.mp3"];
  NSURL    *audio_inputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audio_inputFilePath];

  // this is the video file that was just written above, full path to file is in --> videoOutputPath
  NSURL    *video_inputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoOutputPath];

  // create the final video output file as MOV file - may need to be MP4, but this works so far...
  NSString *outputFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"final_video.mp4"];
  NSURL    *outputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputFilePath];

  if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:outputFilePath])
      [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:outputFilePath error:nil];

  CMTime nextClipStartTime = kCMTimeZero;

  AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:video_inputFileUrl options:nil];
  CMTimeRange video_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,videoAsset.duration);
  AVMutableCompositionTrack *a_compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
  [a_compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:video_timeRange ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];

  //nextClipStartTime = CMTimeAdd(nextClipStartTime, a_timeRange.duration);

  AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:audio_inputFileUrl options:nil];
  CMTimeRange audio_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration);
  AVMutableCompositionTrack *b_compositionAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
  [b_compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:audio_timeRange ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];

  //AVAssetExportSession* _assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
  __block AVAssetExportSession* _assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];

  NSLog(@"support file types= %@", [_assetExport supportedFileTypes]);
  _assetExport.outputFileType = @"com.apple.quicktime-movie";
  NSLog(@"support file types= %@", [_assetExport supportedFileTypes]);
  _assetExport.outputURL = outputFileUrl;

  [_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
      switch (_assetExport.status) {
          case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
              // Custom method to import the Exported Video
              NSLog(@"completed!!!");
              break;
          case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
              //
              NSLog(@"Failed:%@",_assetExport.error);
              break;
          case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
              //
              NSLog(@"Canceled:%@",_assetExport.error);
              break;
          default:
              break;
      }
  }];

  ///// THAT IS IT DONE... the final video file will be written here...
  NSLog(@"DONE.....outputFilePath--->%@", outputFilePath);

  // the final video file will be located somewhere like here:
  // /Users/caferrara/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/D4B12FEE-E09C-4B12-B772-7F1BD6011BE1/Documents/outputFile.mov

}

Comment: This code encodes images and not H264 sample buffers; the OP is requesting the latter.